# Creating a guice injector with two different modules having similar dependencies

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

Suppose I have two modules `ModuleA` and `ModuleB` which are self-sufficient and can be used as stand-alone modules. Both the modules have a dependency on a third module `ModuleC` like

```
install(new ModuleC());
```

Now, I have a use case where I need to create an injector with both modules, A and B. I did this:

```
Guice.createInjector(new ModuleA(), new ModuleB());
```

It threw a `CreationException` as expected which said that a binding to a certain class was already configured at one of the modules. Keeping in mind that I do not have the power to alter `ModuleA` and `ModuleB`, how do I make it work?

I tried using `Modules.combine(Modules... modules)` but that did not solve my problem. Is there any solution out there for this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consider you have the following bindings defined:

**ModuleC**:

- C1

**ModuleA**

- A1
- A2

**ModuleB**

- B1
- B2

Now when you do `Guice.createInjector(new ModuleA(),new ModuleB())` or `Modules.combine(..)`,
your final list of bindings will be:

- A1
- A2
- B1
- B2
- C1 (as inherited from A)
- C1 (!) (as inherited from B)

as C1 binding is listed twice, that creates a conflict and results in `CreationException`.

But if you use [Modules.override()](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/google/inject/Module.html) instead:

> Returns a builder that creates a module that overlays override modules over the given modules. If a key is bound in both sets of modules, only the binding from the override modules is kept.

E.g. by doing

```
Modules.override(new ModuleA()).with(new ModuleB())
```

Your final list of bindings will be as follows:

- A1
- A2
- B1
- B2
- <del>C1 (as inherited from A)</del>
- C1 (as inherited from B)

The C1 binding inherited from **ModuleA** will be dropped in favor of the C1 binding as defined in **ModuleB**, thus resolving the conflict.

Comment: I tried

`Guice.createInjector(Modules.override(new ModuleA(), new ModuleB()).with(new ModuleC()));`

Comment: This worked. `Guice.createInjector(Modules.override(new ModuleA()).with(new ModuleB())`. Thanks. But can you elaborate your answer a bit?

Comment: Downvoted because [Modules.override()](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/3.0/javadoc/com/google/inject/util/Modules.html#override(com.google.inject.Module...)) says "Prefer to write smaller modules that can be reused and tested without overrides."

Answer (score -1):

The documentation for [Modules.override()](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/3.0/javadoc/com/google/inject/util/Modules.html#override(com.google.inject.Module...)) says "Prefer to write smaller modules that can be reused and tested without overrides." For production code, here are a few alternatives:

- Refactor `ModuleA` and `ModuleB` to not install `ModuleC` and install `ModuleC` when you create the injector. This makes it more clear that bindings in `ModuleC` are shared between modules A and B.
- Make `ModuleA` and `ModuleB` each a [PrivateModule](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/3.0/javadoc/com/google/inject/PrivateModule.html) so that the `ModuleC` bindings are not shared and, therefore, cannot conflict. The potential downside is that now `ModuleA` and `ModuleB` will not share bindings (e.g. could be problematic for Singletons and Multibinders).
- Annotate the bindings in `ModuleA` &or `ModuleB` so that they do not share bindings. Then, when they install ModuleC, they tell `ModuleC` (through its constructor) what the binding annotation should be. This option would be more suitable if you think the bindings for `ModuleA` and `ModuleB` could diverge in the future or if the bindings must not be shared. You could also make `ModuleC` a [PrivateModule](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/3.0/javadoc/com/google/inject/PrivateModule.html) so that it only needs to annotate the bindings it exposes.

Comment: The poster specifically said he can not alter the modules.